# Autoload Laravel Exceptions

Tags: php, laravel, exception, eloquent

I'm working with Eloquent Models, which throw the `ModelNotFound` exception when we use the `findOrFail()` method.

I have a global handler to this exception, set in the file global.php.

But I would like to show to the user appropriate messages, so I have to handle these exceptions locally, using `try/catch`.

The "problem" is that I wouldn't like to import the file all the time, or use the complete namespace like this:

```
try {
    Model::findOrFail();
} catch(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    //do something here
}
```

Isn't there a way to autoload this file?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "appropriate messages?" like per user or per "model"? There is a way to make generic handling of this exception.

Comment: @Kyslik Per model. For example, I have the "Product" model in the "Entries" controller, and I'm using the "Product" `findOrFail()` method inside this controller. So, I would like to show a message about the error, but related with this "Entries" functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this and it seems to work fine.  What I did was added the following to the `aliases` array in `config/app.php`.

```
'ModelNotFoundException' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
```

And now you should be able to catch that exception by doing the following...

```
try {
    throw new \ModelNotFoundException('Some Message');
} catch (\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();  // Should echo "Some Message"
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work!! It seems that the global handler overrides the local one. When I throw the exception, as you did in the example, the exception is caught by the `try/catch`. But, when we wait for the exception thrown by the `findOrFail` method, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question; if all you what you want to do is autoload that `global.php` file, you can simply add it to your `composer.json` file like:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Http/global.php" // <-- Or wherever your file lives
    ]
```

Then just execute a `composer dump auto-load -o` or the like, and now you'll have access to this file/all functions within the file, anywhere in your application.

Comment: No! I got your point, but I would like to autoload the file that contains the exception, the ModelNotFoundException.php file

Comment: @VictorLeal okay, I see. Seems user3158900's answer is more appropriate then.